# Chrome Extension: How to bind 'keyup' event to the onCommands API in the manifest.json file

Tags: google-chrome-extension, keyboard-events

I'm working on a chrome extension which performs certain actions based on commands received from the event page. I registered the commands in the manifest.json file using commands API https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands. While trying out my extension, I found that when I press and hold the registered keys it continuously fires keydown event and performs the required function repeatedly which I don't want to happen.

This is manifest.json

```
    "commands": {
        "doFirstThing": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Alt+V",
                "mac": "Alt+V"
            },
            "description": "something something"
        },
        "doSecondThing": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Alt+B",
                "mac": "Alt+B"
            },
            "description": "something something"
        }
    }
```

And this is background.js which is an Event Page

```
    chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function (command) {
    switch (command) {
        case "doFirstThing":
            //do something
            break;

        case "doSecondThing":
            //do something
            break;
        }
    });
```

So when I press and hold Alt and then press and release 'V' everything works fine. But, when I press and hold 'V' as well the 'doFirstThing' commands executes repeatedly. It looks like keydown event is fired up. Is there a way to bind keyup event to onCommands API so that my functions runs only once?

Comment: Repeating a pressed key is the standard historical behavior for all apps except games. You can check the last time your code ran by comparing `performance.now()` against its previous value stored in a variable.

Comment: Yes, that could be one of the solution. However, javaScript has 'keyup' event which is fired only once. I was looking for a way to bind 'keyup' event to my commands in manifest.json. I searched everywhere, but found nothing. @wOxxOm

Comment: The chrome.commands API doesn't use keyup so if you need the latter, you'll have to abandon the former and attach the keyup listeners in your content script. It won't work in the address bar and inside Chrome's own UI pages like settings, downloads, bookmarks, etc.

Comment: Okay, Thank You. @wOxxOm